# Can't Run Emulator on Eclipse and Always Get Same Error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

i just try to edit my old android source code which i build before android studio release. I want to edit it on my Eclipse Neon, but i don't know what happen, i think all the setting was correct but this what i got when try to run the apps.

[my emulator name is wtf and it just error like that all time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnqd3.png)

[This my emulator detail,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHIPZ.png)

Please master help me to solve this problem, any comment will be very appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: The Emulator is installed from Eclipse or Android Studio? How about just launching a emulator without running your app? Does it crash again? I just wanna know whether its your code or the emulator that cause the error. And do you know how to import a project from Android Studio to Eclipse?

Comment: Emulator is installed on Eclipse. When i run the emulator from eclipse AVD manager, it's run smoothly. Just when i try to run from app, it will crash. I have try 3 different source code for different apps and all of them had same result, the emulator crash. My project is basically made on Eclipse, but i made it about 2 years ago, and now i want to do some tweak on my apps so i install again eclipse on my OS X but i don't know what cause the error.